# vanilla javascript rendering plane text RAILS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been using vanilla javascript and im just rendering a simple alert message but it renders the JS code as plane string in view. Here is my code

```
def index
render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');"
end
```

It renders the same string "alert('Hello Rails');" for me in view instead of a alert message.
Im in Rails 3 and as Rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) the code looks ok.

Any answers would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare two following snippets:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    alert('Hello Rails');
    </script>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    alert('Hello Rails');
</body>
</html>
```

First one generates alert message, second just shows the the string. Browsers do not execute JS code unless it is wrapped with `<script>` tag. jQuery ajax calls in the @Erez answer also wrap response with `<script>` internally.

So if you access your action directly try to wrap it with `<script>` , or, better, use javascript_tag helper (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag)

Comment: You are right @dimuch, do you mean i should replace my line in controller to render :js => "<script>alert('test')</script>" ? Isn't render :js automatically wrap the <script> tag around it?

Comment: Yes, render :js does not wrap the response with `<script>`, it just sets correct content-type. You should use render :js when you process ajax call or script inclusion. If you expect javascript execution on regular page, try to use regular view with inline javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering JS ok. The problem is with the browser which receives this JS and displays it as plain text.

Try sending an AJAX request with (using JQuery here):

```
$.ajax(url: '/index/url', type: 'GET', dataType: 'script')
```

Note that the dataType is set to script, meaning JQuery will execute the returned text as JS.

The short version for this would be

```
$.getScript('/index/url');
```

Comment: Thanks Erez, I have tried it in Chrome and FF, and when i have observed that in "Network" Tab of Chrome dev tool, the type of response is "text/javascript" which means the browser is also recieving the correct request

Comment: The type of the response is one thing, and how the browser processes the response is another thing. Did you try the AJAX calls as I mentioned them?

Comment: Using the AJAX call isn't making sense to me in my case, actully i have a submit button and hit goes to a different action where i am trying to render JS for a particular case, so this AJAX call will not fit for that case, but in general scenario, your solution seems to be good.

Comment: Do you have any other idea? Thanks